# Rails 4 - dynamically populate 2nd select menu based on choice in first select menu in a nested form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, select, drop-down-menu

I have models for Project and Ethic in my Rails 4 app.

The ethics view has a nested fields form (using simple form simple fields for) contained in it. The ethic form fields are nested in the projects form.

The ethic form fields has 2 select menus.  The first menu offers a set of options for a category. The 2nd select option is a list of subcategories.

I'm trying to figure out how to populate the 2nd select menu with the right options, based on the choice made in the 1st select menu.

In my project.js file, I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   jQuery("#project_ethic_attributes.main_category").change(function() {
      var category = $("#project_ethic_attributes.main_category").val(),
        sub_category = $("#project_ethic_attributes.sub_category"),
        options = [],
        str = "";
      sub_category.find('option').remove();
      if(category == 'Risk of harm'){
      options = ["Physical Harm", "Psychological distress or discomfort", "Social disadvantage", "Harm to participants", "Financial status", "Privacy"]
    }

   });

   // jQuery(".main_category").change(function() {
   //  var category = $(".main_category").val(),
   //      sub_category = $(".sub_category"),
   //      options = [],
   //      str = "";
   //  sub_category.find('option').remove();

   //  if(category == 'Risk of harm'){
   //    options = ["Physical Harm", "Psychological distress or discomfort", "Social disadvantage", "Harm to participants", "Financial status", "Privacy"]
   //  }
   //  else if(category == 'Informed consent'){
   //    options = ["Explanation of research", "Explanation of participant's role in research"]   
   //  }
   //  else if(category == 'Anonymity and Confidentiality'){
   //    options = ["Remove identifiers", "Use proxies", "Disclosure for limited purposes"]
   //  }
   //  else if(category == 'Deceptive practices'){
   //    options = ["Feasibility"]
   //  }
   //  else if(category == 'Right to withdraw'){
   //    options = ["Right to withdraw from participation in the project"]  
   //  }
   //  if(options.length > 0){
   //    for(i=0;i<options.length;i++){
   //      str = '<option value="' + options[i] + '">' + options[i] + '</option>'
   //      sub_category.append(str);
   //    }
   //    sub_category.val(options[0]);
   //  }


});
```

I can't figure out what Im doing wrong. Regardless of the choice I make in the 1st option, the 2nd select menu is populated with options that belong to the last category.

My projects form has:

```
 <%= f.simple_fields_for :ethics do |f| %>
        <%= render 'ethics/ethic_fields', f: f %>
 <% end %>
 <%= link_to_add_association 'Add an ethics consideration', f, :ethics, partial: 'ethics/ethic_fields' %>
```

My ethic form fields has:

```
<%= f.input :category, collection: [ "Risk of harm", "Informed consent", "Anonymity and Confidentiality", "Deceptive practices", "Right to withdraw"], :label => "Principle",  prompt: 'select', id: "main_category" %>


            <%= f.input :subcategory,  collection: text_for_subcategory(@category), :label => "Subcategory", prompt: 'select', id: "sub_category" %>
```

My ethic view helper has:

```
def text_for_subcategory(category)
      if category == 'Risk of harm'
            [ "Physical Harm", "Psychological distress or discomfort", "Social disadvantage", "Harm to participants", "Financial status", "Privacy"]
        elsif category == 'Informed consent'
            ["Explanation of research", "Explanation of participant's role in research"]
        elsif category == 'Anonymity and Confidentiality'
            ["Remove identifiers", "Use proxies", "Disclosure for limited purposes"]
        elsif category == 'Deceptive practices' 
            ["Feasibility"] 
        else category == 'Right to withdraw'    
            ["Right to withdraw from participation in the project"] 
       end
    end
```

Can anyone see what i need to do to populate the second select menu with the right options based on the choice made in the 1st select menu. I'm wondering if I'm not supposed to write the jQuery in the project.js file, given the form fields are contained within an ethic view partial (rendered in the projects form).

**MIXAN'S SUGGESTION**

My form now has:

```
<%= f.input :category, collection: [ "Risk of harm", "Informed consent", "Anonymity and Confidentiality", "Deceptive practices", "Right to withdraw"], option:'disabled selected value', :label => "Principle",  prompt: 'select', id: "main_category" %>


        <%= f.input :subcategory,  :label => "Subcategory", prompt: 'select', id: "sub_category", option:'disabled' %>
```

I had to change the form a bit because I use simple form with rails. I'm not sure if I have added the 'disabled selected value' and 'disabled' options to the form inputs correctly.

At the moment, the form renders- but the second menu is not populated with any content. I wonder if that has something to do with the use of the option tags in the js file?

ethics.js has:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var optionsMap = {
      'Risk of harm': [
        'Physical Harm', 
        'Psychological distress or discomfort', 
        'Social disadvantage', 
        'Harm to participants', 
        'Financial status', 
        'Privacy'
      ],
      'Informed consent': [
        'Explanation of research', 
        "Explanation of participant's role in research"
      ],
      'Anonymity and Confidentiality': [
        'Remove identifiers', 'Use proxies', 'Disclosure for limited purposes'
      ],
      'Deceptive practices': [
        'Feasibility'
      ],
      'Right to withdraw': [
        'Right to withdraw from participation in the project'
      ]
    };

  jQuery('#main_category').change(function() {
    var category = jQuery(this).val(),
        $subCategory = jQuery('#sub_category'),
        newOptions = optionsMap[category];
    $subCategory.attr('disabled', false)
    $subCategory.empty();
    $.each(newOptions, function() {
      $subCategory.append(jQuery("<option></option>").text(this));
    });
  })
});
```

**MIXAN'S AMENDED SUGGESTION**

```
<%= f.select :category, collection: [ "Risk of harm", "Informed consent", "Anonymity and Confidentiality", "Deceptive practices", "Right to withdraw"], option:'disabled selected value', :label => "Principle", prompt: 'select', html: { id: "main_category" } %>


<%= f.select :subcategory, [], {}, id: "sub_category", disabled: true %>
```

When I try this, the formatting of the menu drop down for the first category is changed, but the functionality is the same as when I use f.input. The second menu does not populate with any options though.

Comment: i would go about using ajax for this case. [Rails Ajax](https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy), still use your jquery to detect a change in the first select list, then trigger a controller action via ajax to reload the second list

Comment: If the second field's data is not being changed by some form of admin panel, then you can easily implement this in your JS. Otherwise you need to use AJAX to fetch the options for second field once the user has selected the first field.

Comment: @JagjotSingh - the subcategories for each category are defined in my helper.

Comment: @Mel that means they will be pretty static and not changing much right?

Comment: That's right - they are unlikely to change

Comment: @Mel then the most easiest way to implement it would be in JS. The JS code you mentioned in your question is in the right direction, can I know what issue did you face with it?

Comment: @JagjotSingh - when I try the js I wrote, the second menu is populated with the option for the last value in the first table (every time). If I pick options 1,2,3 or 4 from the first menu, then that's the wrong outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In provided example seems that you selecting wrong DOM elements. Just reference them by id, it will be more clear and it will be not so coupled with attributes naming. 
I suggesting the next approach for your task.
First build the map of selects on client side:

```
var optionsMap = {
    'Risk of harm': [
      'Physical Harm', 
      'Psychological distress or discomfort', 
      'Social disadvantage', 
      'Harm to participants', 
      'Financial status', 
      'Privacy'
    ],
    'Informed consent': [
      'Explanation of research', 
      "Explanation of participant's role in research"
    ],
    'Anonymity and Confidentiality': [
      'Remove identifiers', 'Use proxies', 'Disclosure for limited purposes'
    ],
    'Deceptive practices': [
      'Feasibility'
    ],
    'Right to withdraw': [
      'Right to withdraw from participation in the project'
    ]
  };
```

Then just listen for changes of main select and rebuild options for sub select.

```
jQuery('#main_category').change(function() {
  var category = jQuery(this).val(),
      $subCategory = jQuery('#sub_category'),
      newOptions = optionsMap[category];

  $subCategory.empty();
  $.each(newOptions, function(key,value) {
    $subCategory.append(jQuery("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
  });
})
```

Here an example how it looks like with plain html form

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var optionsMap = {
      'Risk of harm': [
        'Physical Harm', 
        'Psychological distress or discomfort', 
        'Social disadvantage', 
        'Harm to participants', 
        'Financial status', 
        'Privacy'
      ],
      'Informed consent': [
        'Explanation of research', 
        "Explanation of participant's role in research"
      ],
      'Anonymity and Confidentiality': [
        'Remove identifiers', 'Use proxies', 'Disclosure for limited purposes'
      ],
      'Deceptive practices': [
        'Feasibility'
      ],
      'Right to withdraw': [
        'Right to withdraw from participation in the project'
      ]
    };

  jQuery('#main_category').change(function() {
    var category = jQuery(this).val(),
        $subCategory = jQuery('#sub_category'),
        newOptions = optionsMap[category];
    $subCategory.attr('disabled', false)
    $subCategory.empty();
    $.each(newOptions, function() {
      $subCategory.append(jQuery("<option></option>").text(this));
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id='main_category'>
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option>Risk of harm</option>
    <option>Informed consent</option>
    <option>Anonymity and Confidentiality</option>
    <option>Deceptive practices</option>
    <option>Right to withdraw</option>
  </select>
  <select id='sub_category' disabled>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. I can see that your code snippet works great in this example. I'm struggling to plug it in to my code though. It might be something to do with the simple form collection structure. I updated my post to show what's in the code now. I can't substitute the form elements the way you have shown in your example.

Comment: The form renders without any errors - but the second menu is empty.

Comment: @Mel I read your new example.
This seems incorrect for me
`<%= f.input :subcategory,  :label => "Subcategory", prompt: 'select', id: "sub_category", option:'disabled' %>`
Use select instead
`<%= f.select :subcategory, [], {}, id: "sub_category", disabled: true %>`

Here the full doc for this input
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select

Comment: I tried it that way. It renders the page, with an empty select menu for the 2nd input field.

Comment: It should be intialy empty, and after choosing value on first select it should activate. Is it always empty in your case?

Comment: yes - it doesnt update when i choose something from the 1st menu

Comment: @Mel can you check whats the html you get on the output?

Comment: <select class="select optional form-control" name="project[ethics_attributes][0][category]" id="project_ethics_attributes_0_category"><option value="">select</option>
<option value="Risk of harm">Risk of harm</option>
<option value="Informed consent">Informed consent</option>
<option value="Anonymity and Confidentiality">Anonymity and Confidentiality</option>
<option value="Deceptive practices">Deceptive practices</option>
<option value="Right to withdraw">Right to withdraw</option></select>

Comment: <select id="sub_category" disabled="disabled" name="project[ethics_attributes][0][subcategory]"></select>

Comment: As you can see main select doesn't pick the id attribute as you have to pass html attrs under html key <%= f.input :category, collection: [ "Risk of harm", "Informed consent", "Anonymity and Confidentiality", "Deceptive practices", "Right to withdraw"], option:'disabled selected value', :label => "Principle",  prompt: 'select', html: { id: "main_category" } %>

Comment: I tried the line as you wrote it, but I still get an empty drop down for the second menu

Comment: Then just use f.select form builder method, as it proposed specially for selects

Comment: The menu is empty when I write it like this:    <%= f.select :subcategory, [], {}, id: "sub_category", disabled: true %>

Comment: I mean for main select to for subcategory select. The problem that there is  incorrect `id` in generate html select

Comment: It still gives an empty second menu. I added the updated form elements above so you can see the changes I made. I would love to get this working like you've managed in your example. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @Mel please read documentation more careful, you are using select api totally incorrect.
it should be:

`
<%= f.select :category, [ "Risk of harm", "Informed consent", "Anonymity and Confidentiality", "Deceptive practices", "Right to withdraw"], { label: "Principle" }, id: "main_category" %>
`

Comment: Thank you so  much. I have no idea how to figure out what the API documentation means. I wish someone would write a sentence in plain english to say which parts of the examples are necessary in using the various gems. It's a huge barrier to learning to have a big black whole between the docs and what is assumed knowledge. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code, edit it for your `#id`'s and `urls`

```
// Dynamic Search Model Loader
$(function(){
    var saved = {};
    var options, value;
    $("#selectOne").change(function(){
        options = '<option value="" selected="selected">Loading...</option>';
        $("#selectTwo").html(options);
        value = $(this).val();

        if (saved[value].length > 0) {
           $("#selectTwo").html(saved[value]);
        } else {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/api/get-json-values/?category=' + value, // Set the category as the value or whatever you want it to be
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true
        }).done(function(data){
            options = '<option value="" selected="selected">Please Pick...</option>';
            // Parse through the values
            $.each(data, function(text){
                options += '<option value="' + text + '">' + text + '</option>';
            });
            // Populate the second select menu
            $("#selectTwo").html(options);
            saved[value] = options;
          }).fail(function(data){
            options = '<option value="" selected="selected">Empty...</option>';
            $("#selectTwo").html(options);
          }); // End Ajax
         };
    }); // End Change
});
```

*Repeat it as needed for the other select menus*

---

**Requires you to create an action in your controller that returns a JSON with the values you want.**

** Routes.rb **

```
namespace :api do
    get 'get-json-values', to: 'queries#category_search'
end
```

Controller Code:

```
class API::Queries < ApplicationController

  def category_search
    category = params[:category]

    if category == 'Risk of harm'
      @json = [ "Physical Harm", "Psychological distress or discomfort", "Social disadvantage", "Harm to participants", "Financial status", "Privacy"]
    elsif category == 'Informed consent'
      @json = ["Explanation of research", "Explanation of participant's role in research"]
    elsif category == 'Anonymity and Confidentiality'
      @json = ["Remove identifiers", "Use proxies", "Disclosure for limited purposes"]
    elsif category == 'Deceptive practices' 
      @json = ["Feasibility"] 
    elsif category == 'Right to withdraw'    
      @json = ["Right to withdraw from participation in the project"] 
    else
      @json = nil
    end

    if @json
      render json: @json.to_json, status: 200
    else
      render json: {message: 'Not Found'}, status: 404
    end
  end
end
```

It will then go though them and add them as options to the *slave* select menu

Comment: Thans for the suggestion. I don't understand how to follow the instructions in your js code. Have you got an example of how to set the category / parse through the values? Or any thoughts on where I can find info on how to do that? Also, can I use this in my project when I'm using jqeury?

Comment: this ajax call is absolutely redundant, this if else statements can be resolved on client side

Comment: @mixan946 Yes it is overkill, one day he may want to query data from the DB

Comment: @blnc even if he want pick data from db, there is no reason to query this data each time select is changed.